Deleting selected element in a doubly linked list
I have written a code on deleting a node by comparing its data from the data given. If equal, it deletes the node. My problem is that my code will delete every node in the list except the last node, I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so I seeked the help as usual
Code is duly attached. Hope someone helps me.
(edit: the code has been modified in accordance with the mistakes)
int dl_delete_element(Dlist **head, Dlist **tail, int data)
{
    Dlist *temp,*prev;
    if(*head==NULL)
        return FAILURE;
    temp=*head;
    if(temp->data==data)
    {
        prev=*head;
        (temp->next)->prev=NULL;
        *head=temp->next;
        free(prev);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->data==data)
            {
                prev=temp;
                (temp->prev)->next=temp->next;
                (temp->next)->prev=temp->prev;
                free(prev);
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            else
                temp=temp->next;
        }
        return DATA_NOT_FOUND;
    }
}


White space is cheap and makes it easier to read your code.  For example, instead of if(temp->data==data), use if (temp->data == data).  Note that the dot . and arrow -> operators bind very tightly (as do array subscripts); they should not have spaces around them.

If there's one element in the list (so (*head)->next == NULL), then you delete the element whether it matches the data or not.  That is not desirable.

Let's try something simple.

Find which element to delete.
 Dlist* cur = *head;
 while (cur != NULL && cur->data != data) 
     cur = cur->next;
 if (cur == NULL) 
     return FAILURE; // or DATA_NOT_FOUND? What other failures are there?


Delete it.
 if (cur == *head) 
    *head = cur->next;
 else 
    cur->prev->next = cur->next;

 if (cur == *tail) 
    *tail = cur->prev;
 else 
    cur->next->prev = cur->prev;

 free(cur);
 return SUCCESS;



Looks good? Caveat: this code is untested. If you find a bug, fix it!

With the statement (temp->next)->prev=temp->prev; you dereference temp->next without first checking whether that pointer is not null. It will be null when temp is the tail node. In that case you get undefined behaviour. Instead you should update the tail reference.
Another issue in your code is that when the list has only one element, you delete that element without even checking whether the data matches.
I would not return FAILURE when the list is empty. There is nothing wrong about that; it is just that you will not find a node with the target data, so just return DATA_NOT_FOUND in that case.
I would also avoid some code repetition, and split functionality into separate functions, like a function for finding the node, and another for removing a node by its reference. Specifically you should only have one place where you free a node.
Here is a correction:
// Delete a node given its reference (not data):
void dl_delete_node(Dlist **head, Dlist **tail, Dlist *node) {
    if (node == *head) { // When it is the first node
        *head = node->next;
        if (*head) {
            (*head)->prev = NULL;
        } else {
            *tail = NULL;    
        }
    } else if (node == *tail) { // When it is the last node
        *tail = node->prev;
        (*tail)->next = NULL;
    } else { // When the node is neither first nor last
        node->prev->next = node->next;
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }
    free(node);
}

// Find a node that has given data, or NULL when not found
Dlist *dl_find(Dlist *head, int data) {
    while (head && head->data != data) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    return head;
}

// Use the above two functions for removing 
//   the first node that has the given data
int dl_delete_element(Dlist **head, Dlist **tail, int data)
{
    Dlist *node = dl_find(*head, data);
    if (!node) {
        return DATA_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    dl_delete_node(head, tail, node);
    return SUCCESS;
}


For starters your list design is bad. Apart from the structure that contains the definition of the node you should introduce one more structure that will contain only pointers to the head and tail nodes like for example
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
    int data;
} Node;

typedef struct Dlist
{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail'
} Dlist;

In this case your function declaration would look simpler like
int dl_delete_element( Dlist *list, int data );

Nevertheless as for your current list design then the function dl_delete_element does not even use its parameter Dlist **tail.
And apart from that it contains bugs in other control flows of the code. For example if the list contains only one node and its data member data is equal to the parameter data  then this code snippet
if(temp->data==data)
{
    prev=*head;
    (temp->next)->prev=NULL;
    *head=temp->next;
    free(prev);
    return SUCCESS;
}

invokes undefined behavior due to using a null pointer in this statement
    (temp->next)->prev=NULL;

becuase the expression temp->next yields a null pointer.
Using your approach to the function definition the function can be defined simply the following way
int dl_delete_element( Dlist **head, Dlist **tail, int data )
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    while ( *head != NULL && ( *head )->data != data )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        return DATA_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    else
    {
        Dlist *current = *head;
        *head = current->next;

        if (*head == NULL)
        {
            *tail = current->prev;
        }
        else
        {
            ( *head )->prev = current->prev;
        }

        free( current );

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

Here is a demonstration program. Concreate values of the used enumerators SUCCESS, FAILURE and DATA_NOT_FOUND are unimpotant for the function definition.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Dlist
{
    struct Dlist *prev;
    struct Dlist *next;
    int data;
} Dlost;

enum { SUCCESS = 0, FAILURE = -1, DATA_NOT_FOUND = 1 };

int dl_delete_element( Dlist **head, Dlist **tail, int data )
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    while ( *head != NULL && ( *head )->data != data )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        return DATA_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    else
    {
        Dlist *current = *head;
        *head = current->next;

        if (*head == NULL)
        {
            *tail = current->prev;
        }
        else
        {
            ( *head )->prev = current->prev;
        }

        free( current );

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

int append( Dlist **head, Dlist **tail, int data )
{
    Dlost *new_node = malloc( sizeof( *new_node ) );

    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->prev = *tail;

        if (*head == NULL) *head = new_node;
        else ( *tail )->next = new_node;

        *tail = new_node;

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

void display( const Dlist *head )
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

void reverse_display( const Dlist *tail )
{
    for (; tail != NULL; tail = tail->prev)
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", tail->data );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

int main( void )
{
    Dlist *head = NULL;
    Dlist *tail = NULL;

    const int N = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        append( &head, &tail, i );
        display( head );
        reverse_display( tail );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    for (int i = N; i != 0; i--)
    {
        dl_delete_element( &head, &tail, i - 1 );
        display( head );
        reverse_display( tail );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

The program output is
0 -> null

0 -> 1 -> null
1 -> 0 -> null

0 -> 1 -> 2 -> null
2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null

0 -> 1 -> null
1 -> 0 -> null

0 -> null
0 -> null

null
null

